# Displaying only one record in the table

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to display only a single row in the table. My controller for the same looks like this:

```
def Add
    @item= Item.find(params[:id])
end
```

and my table row looks like this.. Isn't there a substitute for the method `.each` to just display one record?

```
<% @item.each do |item| %>
<tr>
   <td><%= item.name %></td>
   <td><%= item.price %></td>
   <td><%= item.quantity %></td>
   <td><%= item.quantity * item.price %></td>
   <td>
      <% link_to("update", '#', :class => 'action update') %>
      <% link_to("X", '#', :class => 'action delete') %>
   </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you don't need loop. U can directly create table like this

```
<tr>
  <td><%= @item.name %></td>
  <td><%= @item.price %></td>
  <td><%= @item.quantity %></td>
  <td><%= @item.quantity * @item.price %></td>
  <td>
    <% link_to("update", '#', :class => 'action update') %>
    <% link_to("X", '#', :class => 'action delete') %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@item= Item.find(params[:id])
```

Here, @item will be an object of class Item. So You don't need to Iterate the Object with 'each'. You can directly access the Item attribute by @item object.

```
@item.name
@item.price
@item.quantity.....
```